# long running running job in flask

Tags: python, celery, python-multithreading

I have created a module that does some heavy computations, and returns some data to be stored in a nosqldatabase. The computation process is started via a post request in my flask application. The flask function will execute the cumputation code and after the code and then the returned results will be stored in db. I was thinking of celery. But I am wondering and haven't found any clear info on that if it would be possible to use python trheading E.g

```
from mysci_module import heavy_compute


@route('/initiate_task/', methods=['POST',])
def run_computation():
    import thread
    thread.start_new_thread(heavy_compute, post_data)

    return reponse
```

Its very abstract I know. The only problem I see in this method is that my function will have to know and be responsible in storing data in the database, so It is not very independant on the database used. Correct? Why is Celery a better (is it really?) than the method above?

Answer (score 1):

Since CPython is restricted from true concurrency using threads by the GIL, all computations will infact happen serially. Instead you could use the python multiprocessing module and create a pool of processes to complete your heavy computation task.

There are a few microframeworks such as [twisted klein](http://tavendo.com/blog/post/going-asynchronous-from-flask-to-twisted-klein/) apart from celery that can also help achieve that concurrency and independence that you're looking for. They aren't necessarily better, but are available for those who don't want to get their hands messy with various issues that are likely to come up when one gets into synchronizing flask and the actual business logic, especially when response is based on that activity.

Comment: So using multiprocess would work. But that would mean that my module function would have to take care of database writing correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Generally, If the response is independent of the heavy task, one may go ahead with the multiprocessing approach itself instead of using celery.

Comment: Aha...I see. I am guessing that would be binding the sci module with a specific database, since it would be responsible for storing data. But otherwise using multiprocess instead of celery is accepted .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following method to start a thread for the long procedure first. Then leave Flask to communicate with the procedure time by time upon your requirements:

```
from mysci_module import heavy_compute

import thread
thread.start_new_thread(heavy_compute, post_data)

@route('/initiate_task/', methods=['POST',])
def check_computation():
    response = heave_compute.status
    return response
```

The best part of this method is to make sure you have a callable thread in the background all the time while it's possible to get the necessary result even passing some parameters to the task.